# How to create an abstract function that returns inherited class type

Tags: kotlin, oop, inheritance

Assume that `A` is an abstract class with an abstract `copy` function that returns type `A`. I want that every inherited class implements `copy` that returns its own class. It is not allowed that `copy` returns the type of `A`.

```kotlin
abstract class A(
  open val property1: String = "A1"
) {
  abstract fun copy(): A
}

class B(
  override val property1: String = "B1",
  val property2: String = "B2"
): A() {
  override fun copy(): B {
    return B(property1 = this.property1, property2 = this.property2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code right now works, if you just change `: A` to `: A()`. What's the problem?

Comment: I want that every inherited class that implements `copy` has to return its own class. Its not allowed to return `A`. I will update the answer to make this more explizit.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could think of is adding a generic to the class declaration :

```
abstract class Test<T> {
    abstract fun copy(): T
}

class Dummy: Test<Dummy>() {
    override fun copy(): Dummy {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be better to restrict the type of `T`: `abstract class Test<T : Test<T>> …`. (The C++ equivalent is called the [curiously-recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern); I don't think the Java/Kotlin version has a specific name, even though it's quite common.)

Comment: As its kinda a restriction, it also is not. In my question the `copy` function of `B` can return `B` like the answer does. Also like the answer it is not limited to return `A` as the super class does not define `itself` as return type. I'd like to have a return type defined in `A` that is refering to the class itself. At `B` the `copy` function then returns `B` by force.